# Integration over a sequence of pushforward measures and convergence

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Recently, as I was trying to solve a problem, a question sprung to mind, so I'll carefully lay it out below.

Consider a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and a nonnegative measurable functions $h : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Since $h$ is nonnegative and measurable, we know that there exists a sequence of nonnegative simple measurable functions $\{ \phi_n \}_{n = 1}^\infty$ such that $\phi_n \uparrow h$.

Now, let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be the Borel measurable space and define the push forward measures $\mu \phi_n^{- 1} : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu h^{- 1} : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation*} 
\mu\phi_n^{- 1}(A) = \mu(\phi_n^{- 1}(A)) \quad \text{and} \quad \mu h^{- 1}(A) = \mu(h^{- 1}(A)) \quad \forall \, A \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}

**Question**: If we define $Id : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the identity function, can we show that the equality below holds?

\begin{equation*}
\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \, \int Id \; \mu\phi_n^{- 1} \, = \, \int Id \; \mu h^{- 1}.
\end{equation*}

What prompted the question was the fact that $\phi_n \uparrow h$, but I don't really know where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add this, but assuming that $Id$ is integrable with respect to $\mu \phi^{- 1}_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and integrable with respect to $\mu h^{- 1}$.

Comment: $\int id \,d(\mu h^{-1}) = \int h \, d\mu$. In different notation, $\int y \, \mu(h \in dy) = \int h(x)\,\mu(dx)$.